# Difference in HTML Entity length in JavaScript

Tags: html, unicode, innerhtml, html-entities, string-length

Why does the entity `&nbsp;` have length 6 while the entity `&darr;` has length 1? Is this in the spec somewhere? (Tested in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/057vs5wg/)

Comment: It's specified in SGML probably, let me have a look

Comment: If I had to guess this is a deliberate bug to maintain backwards compatibility http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm hmm - note that `.textContent` returns 1 in either case.

Comment: Interesting... yes, you're right it does for textContent ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/057vs5wg/1/))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree that this is very weird behavior, but at least it's specified.

The HTML [fragment serialization algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/serializing.html#html-fragment) states that:

> Escaping a string (for the purposes of the algorithm above) consists of replacing any occurrences of the "&" character by the string "&", any occurrences of the "<" character by the string "<", any occurrences of the ">" character by the string ">", **any occurrences of the U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE character by the string " "**, and, if the algorithm was invoked in the attribute mode, any occurrences of the """ character by the string """.

Emphasis by me. If I had to guess this is to support backwards compatibility in older browsers that did this and to get consistent behavior when deserializing and serializing strings. If the browser serialized the DOM tree result of `<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>` to `<div>  </div>` deserializing it to the DOM tree again would result in a single space*. This is pretty much the only way the browser can achieve consistent behavior.

The replacement to `&darr;` on the other hand is completely safe and makes sense.

If you're actually interested in the length of the string stored inside the text using `.textContent` you'd get the result you were interested in.

<sup>* well, not really since it would still be a `&nbsp;` `U+00A0` - but I could get why people think it might be confusing in the early DOM days</sup>

Comment: Thank you for looking this up. However I don't understand how the section you bolded explains the behavior. I should also add that `&gt;` behaves the same way as `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius there is _explicit treatment_ for it in the DOM specification - it, as well as `&`, `&gt;`, `"` and `&lt` are _explicit special cases_ in the DOM specification. In my opinion at least for `&nbsp;` this was to not confuse people with the difference from a normal space (U+0020), but this is indeed a weird case.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the quoted section at first. So what you're saying is that the browser first converts all the entities... and then converts those particular characters back to their entity form? My only question then is why doesn't the browser show `&nbsp;` literally then? I guess I'd need to see the internal representation for this all to make sense.

Comment: Yes, a non breaking space is still a space - " " <- this is one, and it's not a normal space although they look the same. You can see it [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) with all the codes. For reasons I can only estimate are backwards compatibility it gets special treatment by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following HTML snippet:

```
<div>
  <p>foo &amp; bar &#x1D306; baz</p>
</div>
```

Let’s [look up `innerHTML` in the HTML Living Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#dom-innerhtml) to see what happens when we run `div.innerHTML` in the context of the above HTML document. Ah, it defers to [the DOM Parsing spec](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#innerhtml), which says:

> On getting, if the context object’s node document is an HTML document, then the attribute must return the result of running the HTML fragment serialization algorithm on the context object; […]

The HTML fragment serialization algorithm is [defined in the HTML Living Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#html-fragment-serialisation-algorithm). Following the algorithm with the `div.innerHTML` example in mind, it’s clear that the first time it will descend to the “if *current node* is an `Element`” branch under step 3.2. This adds `<p>` to the output.

Then it calls the algorithm again on the text node within. This time we end up in the “if *current node* is a `Text` node” branch. It says:

> […] Otherwise, append the value of *current node*’s `data` IDL attribute, escaped as described below.

The `data` IDL attribute contains the textual contents of the element. The escaping instructions are [defined as follows](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#escapingString):

> Escaping a string (for the purposes of the algorithm above) consists of running the following steps:
>
> 1. Replace any occurrence of the `&` character by the string `&amp;`.
> 2. Replace any occurrences of the U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE character by the string `&nbsp;`.
> 3. If the algorithm was invoked in the attribute mode, replace any occurrences of the `"` character by the string `&quot;`.
> 4. If the algorithm was not invoked in the attribute mode, replace any occurrences of the `<` character by the string `&lt;`, and any occurrences of the `>` character by the string `&gt;`.

Only the abovementioned symbols are escaped as HTML entities in the result of `.innerHTML` – other Unicode symbols are just displayed in their raw form, regardless of how they are represented in the HTML source code.

Because of this, `"&darr;"` in the HTML source code turns into `"↓"` when reading it back out through `innerHTML`. But e.g. `"&amp;"` or `"&#x26;"` turn into `"&amp;"`, and `"&nbsp;"` or `&#xA0;` become `"&nbsp;"`.